# Dot product and orthogonality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Please *only* use the following definition of the dot product:

$u \dot{} v = u^{T}v$

Using the above definiton *only* (**not** the cosine definition) why would the dot product being zero imply the angle between the vectors is 90/-270?

This isn't homework. Please avoid use of the Pythagorean theorem, since my book uses the above result to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean $\pm\pi/2$?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Yes I do. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assumption, we have
$$||u+v||^2=(u+v)^T(u+v)=||u||^2+2u\cdot v+||v||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2$$
And then the orthogonality results from Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Could this be proved without the Phythagorean theorem? Because my book uses this result to prove the theorem. Sorry, I should have included that in my question.

Comment: @dfg Well, how do you definiton of orthogonality

Comment: Two vectors are orthogonal if the angle between them is 90.

Comment: @dfg But since cosine is not allowed here, how do you measure the angle?

Comment: Good point, forget what I said. Thanks for the help.